# Is this Rails cloudfront custom origin setup optimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

I've configured cloudfront to use Heroku as it's custom origin. Inside the `production.rb` file, I made the following setting:

```
middleware.insert_after('Rack::Cache', Rack::Deflater)
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=86400"
config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["ASSET_HOST"]
```

Also, I modified the stylesheets, so that everywhere there was any asset used ( image/font ), I made use of `asset_path`. Therefore, I'm counting on the digest provided by the asset pipeline to expire my assets.

How's this cloudfront setup? Could anything be improved upon, related to the loading of assets?